# Linker error using openCV with fftw3 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, opencv, fftw

I'm having trouble trying to implement fftw3 with openCV in the same project.
I'm new to c/c++ and any help will be much appreciated.
The following is just a sample code i used:

```
 #include "fftw3.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){
     fftw_complex *in, *out;
     fftw_plan p;
     int N=8;
     in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
     out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
     p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        in[i][0]=i;
        in[i][1]=0;
     }
     fftw_execute(p);
     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("R->%f\tI->%f\n", out[i][0], out[i][1]);
     }
     system("pause");
     fftw_destroy_plan(p);
     fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);
 }
```

The code is compiling fine when its in its own project.
But when I'm trying to link the fftw3 and openCV together i get a linker error:

```
    1>video.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fftw_destroy_plan
    1>video.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fftw_execute
    1>video.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fftw_plan_dft_2d
    1>video.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fftw_malloc
    1>video.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fftw_free
    1>D:\C WorkSpace\Viedo_CV\Video test\Release\Video test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
    1>
    1>Build FAILED.
```

I double checked all the linker configurations and they seem to be fine(as i said all is working well when in a separate projects).
The openCV library is working fine.
Unfortunately I can't post my real code.
All the openCV i use is in:

```
    #include <opencv\\cv.h>
    #include <opencv\\highgui.h>
    #include <windows.h>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you include a generic openCV file? I can't picture how you are linking the fftw and openCV libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I don't think i understand what is a "generic openCV file" as i said i'm new to c/c++ and to programing as well. @tir38

Comment: I just mean you are using sample code for the FFTW which is basic and not modified for your specific code. All of the variable names are helpful for us to understand the problem but are not what you will eventually call them for your implementation. I was hoping you could create another file that has a general implementation of your openCV so we can see how openCV relates to FFTW without going into detail of your specific implementation.

Comment: Ohh ok, I understand what you mean now, and the thing is that there is no more code, that was the code i ran and got the linker issue which happens only when i linked the FFT with openCV together with no openCV code at all.

Comment: If it helps I used the "fftw-3.3-libs-visual-studio-2010.zip" project from [link](www.fftw.org) to build the fftw libs and all was working fine until I linked the openCV to the same sample project(with no openCV code not even the #include lines for openCV). @tir38

Comment: First I don't know if the double slash is the problem as in `opencv\\cv.h` but see what happens with single slash. You could also make sure that you have cv.h. A Windows search should tell you. Second, I asked a general question about #include [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095966/what-happens-if-an-include-fails-to-find-file) that might answer your specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out, when I installed openCV I created an environmental variable to the openCV build location and added the openCV DLL's location to the Path variable.
What i didn't notice is that I added the x86 version of the DLL's to the Path variable and my project was setup as x64, the reason it worked in another project is because I copied the x64 DLL's to the project folder it self.
All worked fine after I edited the Path to the correct x64 DLL's location.