# what happens if an #include fails to find file

Tags: c++, include

Say I have this very basic c++ code:

myCode.cpp:

```
#include <library1.h>
#include <library2.h>

int main() {
 // use some methods from library2
}
```

What will happen if I compile this code but my compiler can't find library1.h? Will it throw any specific error? Will it still look for library2.h? Will it skip the rest of the #include statements and go on to compiling main? I'm asking because I'm trying to answer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001780/linker-error-using-opencv-with-fftw3-visual-studio-2010) where adding one .h file is causing the compiler to complain about not finding methods from another .h file . Without the #include first .h line, the code compiles correctly.

Comment: It's a compile-time error: the preprocessor is going to tell you the file is missing, and the compiler is not going to proceed any further.

Comment: You know, you could try it yourself with your favorite compiler to see what happens.

Comment: @Renan I doubt I'm the last person to ever have this question. Besides its a general question and the results of my compiler won't tell me whether all compilers work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler reaches an include error it reports it and stops the compilation. Of course it may be the case that not all compilers will report a human friendly error, but for sure they all will terminate as this error is fatal as syam points out in his comment.

Comment: hmm maybe my wording is misleading, I meant the comment to refer to `When the compiler reaches an include error it reports it`. Can you propose a better wording?

Comment: Ok, perfect now. :) (whoops I realize I just deleted the comment you referred to in your answer)

Comment: @syam: For quite a while (I think 2.6 through 4.3 or so) gcc with certain flags that were only meant to output makefile information degraded missing includes to warnings.

Comment: but the error (human friendly or not) will be about the failure of the include statement, not somewhere else down the line?

Comment: At least this is what happens in compilers I have seen

Answer (score 2):

If a specific `#include` file can't be found, the compilation fails and stops with an error. Compilation can't proceed any further.

Funnily enough, the behaviour in case of a missing header is not explicitly specified. The only relevant part in the Standard is **16.2/1 [cpp.include]**:

> A `#include` directive shall identify a header or source file that can be processed by the implementation.

Note the use of **shall** which gives no choice to the compiler: it *must* replace the `#include` directive by the contents of the file. If the file doesn't exist, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely, if it can't find the file then the compiler won't be able to run the program IF it was needed to run your code correctly. If your code accesses something from that file, the program wont run as needed.